# how to call the parent's open option?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

HTML

```
<div class="dialog"></div><div class="mydialog"></div>
```

// global bind of dialog class - general purpose

```
$('.dialog').dialog({open: function() { alert(1); }});
```

// specific page

```
$('.mydialog').dialog({open: function() { alert(2); }});
```

it seems the specific page open function isn't getting called. how do i call the parent's open and then the child's open (aka, mydialog)?

so i want the output to be alert(1) then alert(2). mydialog's open function isn't getting called at all.

Comment: Could you please add your HTML to the question? Specifically the elements with `class="dialog"` and `class="mydialog"`.

Comment: Excellent. Now a complete question. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('.dialog').dialog({open: function() { alert(1); }, autoOpen:false});
    $('.mydialog').dialog({open: function() {$('.dialog').dialog('open'); alert(2); }});
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/UdrvD/1/

You can see I added `autoOpen:false` to the global `.dialog` config to demonstrate how the `.mydialog` can trigger the event

Comment: +1 from me; looks good. Also @john if this answers solves your problems do you know that you can _accept_ it as the correct solution? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work